How to indicate valid sender domains in OpenSmtpd.?
(Update) Enviroment is Ubuntu server 24.04 and opensmtpd Version: 7.4.0p1-1build4.
Im using Amazon SES with a few validated domains. I don't want to relay emails that are not from authorized domains.
My current smtpd.conf is:
table relay_secrets file:/etc/smtpd/relay_secrets
listen on localhost port 25 mask-src hostname MyDomain.com
listen on socket mask-src
action "relay_ses" relay host smtp+tls://ses@email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 auth <relay_secrets>
match from mail-from "@MyDomain.com" for any action "relay_ses"
match from any reject

And it works:

An email from root@Mydomain.com to MyEmail@gmail.com pass
An email from root@Wrongdomain.com to MyEmail@gmail.com is rejected.

But the error is: Invalid recipient: MyEmail@gmail.com. Not sender error. I guess it is because it is the last rule that is deciding not to send the mail.
Is there any way to indicate which domains (in From part) are valid?

What version of OpenSMTPD are you running?

the lastone on Ubuntu 24.04
#sudo apt show opensmtpd
Package: opensmtpd
Version: 7.4.0p1-1build4

My personal opinion is that OpenSMTPD is the MTA that the vast majority of admins are looking for. As this question demonstrates, we can work out out problems from scratch with enough trial and effort. The current tool most people use is Postfix, which everyone is almost 100% copy-pasting configurations because they have no idea how to create a working configuration from scratch. The issue is that OpenSMTPD is poorly supported for ports, but fortunately it is very well maintained as a part of OpenBSD.

I agree. OpenSMTPD is simple but powerful enough. And it is easy to extend. I'm not sure I would choose it for something very complex. But what I need is an MTA-alias of sendmail that is easy to configure and can be put on servers to handle internal mail.

Solved
table relay_secrets file:/etc/smtpd/relay_secrets
table allowed_domains { "^[^@]+@mydomain\.com$" }

filter goaway phase mail-from match !mail-from regex <allowed_domains> reject "550 go away"

listen on localhost port 25 mask-src hostname mydomain.com filter goaway
listen on socket mask-src filter goaway

action "relay_ses" relay host smtp+tls://ses@email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587 auth <relay_secrets>

match from mail-from regex <allowed_domains> for any action "relay_ses"
match from any reject

The first time I tried to use  filters I made a syntax mistake that did not cause an error, but it did not work. There is no need to re-verify the domains when sending, but my actual setup is a bit more complicated than this and I keep it just in case. I'd really like to not rely on regex for this but I couldn't find anything else and this works. Any other solution?
I'm surprised OpenSMTPD isn't recommended more. Everywhere you find recommendations for sendmail or postfix that are tremendously bloated, or small ones like nullmailer or sSMTP etc, which are limited or buggy.

To specify valid sender domains in OpenSMTPD, set the smtpd_sender_restrictions parameter in the smtpd.conf file. You can specify allowed domains using matching or relaying rules to allow only certain domains to send email. This helps prevent spam and abuse of your SMTP server for outgoing messages.
